# Updatepanel progress bar onclientclick event

Tags: c#, updatepanel, updateprogress, onclientclick, updatepanel-progressbar

I have an Update Progress bar which is working for OnClick event (Server Side), but I need Update Progress bar for OnClientClick event (Client Side).

I have tried below solution but it's not working for me.

**Js:**

```
function ComparableSearch() { 
   $get('UpdateProgress1').style.display = 'block';    
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
   
    GetRefineSearchDetailsMap(StreetNo[0], StreetNo[1], StreetName, State, County, ZipCodeFrom, ZipCodeTo, SalePriceFrom,
                               SalePriceTo, LivingArea, LivingAreaTo, SaleDateFrom, SaleDateTo, SubjectPropertyId, Section, Subdivision,
                               LotSizeFrom, LotSizeTo, YearBuiltFrom, YearBuiltTo, Stories, PrivatePool, FirePlace, Disclosure, IsListing,
                               City, Design, FirePlaceTo);
  
    $("#map").show();
    $("#MainSearchResult").hide();
    return false;
   $get('UpdateProgress1').style.display = 'none';

}



function GetRefineSearchDetailsMap(aStreetNoFrom, aStreetNoTo, aStreetName, aState, aCounty, aZipCodeFrom, aZipCodeTo, aSalePriceFrom,
                                    aSalePriceTo, aLivingArea, aLivingAreaTo, aSaleDateFrom, aSaleDateTo, aSubjectPropertyId, aSection, aSubdivision, aLotSizeFrom,
                                    aLotSizeTo, aYearBuiltFrom, aYearBuiltTo, aStories, aPrivatePool, aFirePlace, aDisclosure, aIsListing, aCity, aDesign, aFirePlaceTo) {


    var SalesSearchCriteria = {        
        X1: X1,
        X2: X2,
        Y1: Y1,
        Y2: Y
    };
    request = $.ajax({
        url: "Form1004/SaleComparableHandler.ashx?type=GetRefineSearchDetailsMap&Tid=" + Math.random(),
        type: "POST",
        data: { "SearchCriteria": JSON.stringify(SalesSearchCriteria) },
        async: true,
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.length > 0) {
                if (data != "Error") {
                    
                }
                else {                    
                    alert("Your session has been expired");
                }
            }
            else {               
                alert("No data exists");
            }
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, status, errorThrown) {
            if (errorThrown != 'abort') {
                PopUpAlertBox("Please try again...<br/><br/>Below error occured <br/><br/> " + errorThrown + "");
            }
            else {
                PopUpAlertBox("Error : " + errorThrown + "");
            }           
        }
    });

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I not mistaken, the Ajax is that you need.

I should create script on client side which will pass data to server (when the event Click is true), the result from server is data for your progress bar.

Small example [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398890%28v=vs.140%29.aspx)

Comment: No.. Here I dont have code in server side. My functionality will work only through client side

Comment: I'm sorry for my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to show an `UpdateProgress` control on javascript

```
$get('UpdateProgress1').style.display = 'block';
```

Similar thing to hide it

```
$get('UpdateProgress1').style.display = 'none';
```

**EDIT**

```
// display indicator before ajax starts
$get('UpdateProgress1').style.display = 'none';

$.ajax({
    url: "Form1004/SaleComparableHandler.ashx?type=GetRefineSearchDetailsMap&Tid=" + Math.random(),
    type: "POST",
    data: { "SearchCriteria": JSON.stringify(SalesSearchCriteria) },
    success: function (data) {
       // your code
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, status, errorThrown) {
       // your code
    }
})
.always(function() {
    // hide ajax indicator when ajax finished (success or error)
    $get('UpdateProgress1').style.display = 'none';
});
```

Comment: @VigneshKumar: does nothing or you get an error? It could be possible that `$` symbol is causing conflicts with jQuery

Comment: No error. but worked nothing. If conflict problem means what should i do?

Comment: I have found root cause of it. This is because of, I am using Ajax Request. In that `Async:False`. If i set `Async:True` its working fine, but i'm afraid of http://forums.asp.net/t/1948919.aspx?Difference+between+async+false+and+async+true+in+ajax

Comment: @Vignesh Kumar: please post your code, `async: true` is almost never the answer

Comment: @Vignesh Kumar: move `$get('UpdateProgress1').style.display = 'none';` inside `always` ajax handler. See my update.

Comment: Thanks but i am not able understand your update. Can you please explain with my code

Comment: @Vignesh Kumar: when async is true (what is ajax default) code doesn't stop waiting for server to return from ajax call. Then, you code to hide the progress indicator is executed inmediatly and not after server replied. It's hard to explain in 3 lines but I recommend you to take a look to how ajax async execution work.

Comment: Yes i know the impact of ajax asyn true. What should I do to indicate the update progress when ajax async is false